# How to read simple xml list with Spring Batch?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

```xml
<parent>
  <child>aaa</child> <!-- simple string -->
  <child>bbb</child>
  ...
</parent>
```

How can I read those children's value and processing with following processor?

```java
@Override
public void write(final List<? extends String> children) {
}
```

Note that I don't have any schedule to make a binding class mapping to `<parent/>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `child` the fragment root element and map its value as `java.lang.String`.

```
<bean name="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
  <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="child" />
  <property name="resource" value="classpath:/xmlStringReader/source.xml" />
  <property name="unmarshaller" ref="unmarshaller" />
</bean>
<bean name="unmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
  <property name="aliases">
    <map>
      <entry key="child" value="java.lang.String" />
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```